# How to save data in ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

I had a made method in *Company* class and calling it in *PayrollApp* class. Firstly! it works fine but whenever I call that method second time it throw *indexoutofboundException*. I am running this app on console without using database. I want to add all employees object into that arraylist.

```
public class Company {
    private ArrayList<Employee> _employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    public void setAddEmployee(Employee c){
        _employeeList.add(c);
    }
}

Employee emp = new Employee(_name, _empId);
emp.setNumOfHoursPerWeek(_hoursPerWeek);
emp.setHourlySalary(_hourlySalary);
emp.setManagerName(_manager);
Company com = new Company();

com.setAddEmployee(emp);
```

Comment: On which line does it occur? Did you Google the exception to make an effort to understand what it is and why it might be happening? Did you step through your code with your debugger?

Comment: To add to an `ArrayList` you simply call `_employeeList.add(c);` No need for the index. That of which never appears to even be initialized.

Comment: probably because you are using a `static int` field for your index counter.  Keep it in scope of the method doing the processing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the index `i` is a static variable of `Company` whereas `ArrayList _employeeList` is not .

So the variable `i` is shared by all instances of your object, whereas your ArrayList `_employeeList` is an instance variable.

So the first time you do `company.setAddEmployee()` , it works fine, because both arrayList is empty as well as i is 0, so it works, and i is incremented to 1.

but next time when you do `company.setAddEmployee()` for a different `company` object, the arrayList for that object is empty, but i is `1` as the variable `i` is static and shared by all instances (Object) of `Company` class.

Either you need to make the `ArrayList` static as well, or you need to make `i` non-static (member variable) , though you may not even need `i` (We can also do `_employeeList.add(<element>)` and it will add at the next available index) , But I cannot comment on how you can fix the issue, since I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with the code.

Comment: I have ArrayList of _Employee. I want that whenever i add a new employee it should also added into that arraylist. And I removed 'i' from code but still not working,

Comment: Are you still get same error? If so , please update the question with latest code and the issue

Comment: @hemant what is the latest error? and from which line? a stack trace would be good.